# How to optimise the speed and memory usage in Caret with parallel computing?

Tags: r, r-caret, parallel.foreach

I'm using caret to find optimal tuning parameter over a large grid. I found using doSnow with caret, memory used up so quickly. Is there some strategy to optimize it?

This is the C50 model, the search grid is as following:

```
mygrid <- expand.grid(trials=c(1, 1:4*10),
                  model=c('rules', 'tree'),
                  winnow=FALSE,
                  fuzzy=c(TRUE, FALSE),
                  cutoff=c(0.01, seq(0.025, 0.5, by=0.025)))
```

1) to save memory, I set trim=TRUE and returnData = FALSE to reduce the individual model size, as following:

```
mycontrol2 <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                      number = 3,#10,
                      repeats = 3,#5,
                      classProbs = TRUE,
                      summaryFunction = fiveStats,
                      verboseIter=TRUE,
                      trim=TRUE, returnData = FALSE #to make the model size smaller.
                      )
```

2) to make the speed faster, I use parallel computing from DoSnow, as following:

```
 library(doSNOW)
 library(parallel)
 cores <- detectCores()
 cl <- makeCluster(cores-2, outfile="")
 registerDoSNOW(cl)
```

However, the process is killed by the Linux system due to out of memory as I monitor via "top" command, the error message is as following.

> Execution halted Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from
>   connection

Here, is there a better way to manage caret training with good speed? Following are some of my thoughts and open for discuss:

1. **make search grid to several small ones and train each individually**. Questions:

   - is there a systematic way to decide the optimal grid size?
   - after dividing, is there a better way to combine the models as I still want to use *plot.train(mod)* method to see the performance graph.
2. **set the number of parallel nodes, i.e., c1, smaller**. Questions:

   - is there a strategy for setting optimal c1 value?

Comment: Does it work if you set: `cores <- detectCores(logical = FALSE)`,?

Comment: @missuse, no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer some questions based on my recent experiences, since you were full of topics.

My away to compute in parallel applying caret is:

```
library(doParallel)
n_cores <- detectCores(); n_cores
# As my pc has three cores, I will use 3 of them: 
registerDoParallel(cores = n_cores - 1)
```

Then, when you tone your trainControl, you could apply:

```
mycontrol2 <- trainControl(
    method = "repeatedcv",
    number = 3,
    repeats = 3,
    classProbs = TRUE,
    verboseIter=TRUE,
    allowParallel = TRUE)
```

Then, you may train your model, and I'll put some lines you could use, since apparently you didn't specify what model you intend to use. The most important is to define the predictors (T1~.), method, data and the trControl, typing something like this:

```
modFit_1 <- train(T1~.,
    method="nnet",
    trControl=cvCtrl, # Here you tune, among others, the "allowParallel"
    data=train,
    metric = "RMSE",
    preProcess = "scale",
    tuneGrid = mygrid)
```

You have other questions and I think they aren't for this topic. But, fastly, related to a "systematic way to decide the optimal grid size" and "models to compare", you may interest for the content of this link: https://rpubs.com/chidungkt/389013, where the authors wrote the strategy, applying caret R package, to compare the performance of five models.

Hey, give your feedback if you got it!
Take care!